# Como crear un layer que puedas cambiarle de color usando codigo de colores en tiempo un juego compilado

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d, color

Osea ingresas un el código del color en una barra(el input) y se cambia el color de un plane

Estuve pensando en usar una shader y hacer bind entre el color y el código

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html

```
   void Start()
   {
       //Create a new cube primitive to set the color on
       GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

       //Get the Renderer component from the new cube
       var cubeRenderer = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();

       //Call SetColor using the shader property name "_Color" and setting the color to red
       cubeRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
   }
```

Ese script se lo pensaba aplicar al label o al plane que quiero que cambie de color

Pero no se como hacer un input para que el usuario ingrese el codigo del color y tampoco como pasarle esa data al script este dentro del plane o label

para el input del código de color, me serviría algo similar a los chats no? Y de ser así como lo hago?

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me quedo así, pero no me anda, porque puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno entiendo con tu pregunta q te refieres a un input.text de UI?
y realize este simple script. cuando el usuario pase el codigo de color llama a SetColor(string nombreDelColor);

```
public class SetColorToInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject plano;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class MyColors {
        public string NameColor;
        public Color color;
    }
    public MyColors[] myColors;
    
    void SetColor(string text)
    {
        foreach (var item in myColors)
        {
            if (item.NameColor==text)
            {
                plano.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", item.color);
            }
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("no color");
    }
}
```